# Need to attach deck ledger to house covering a vent

Tags: deck, ventilation

I am building a deck attached to the house, and on one side I will need to have the ledger covering a section of wall that has a crawlspace vent cover. If I have a big enough gap between the ledger and the siding (maybe bigger than what you would normally do -- make it closer to 3/4" perhaps?) would that be enough space to let air escape through the vent? Or is there some other way to make sure I don't block off the ventilation?

Comment: Is this a dryer vent or a crawlspace vent?

Comment: What kind of vent is this?  An eaves vent or an exhaust vent?

Comment: A deck ledger wouldn't be attached near the eaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave a gap in the ledger where the vent is, then cover that gap with a shorter piece of ledger board that overlaps, and is lag screwed to, the main ledger.  This will give your crawlspace vent 1 1/2" of breathing room, which should be fine for letting your crawlspace breathe.

Comment: That makes sense! Is it OK if decking runs across that area? Air can flow through the 1 1/5" gap and down to under the deck, right?

Comment: Yes, I would run the decking right up to the siding, leaving the bottom of the gap open.  From above you'll never know it's there.  And I think that gap should be plenty to allow air to flow through the vent.